# Theory behind time Series Test dataset being the last x%

Tags: time-series, lstm, data-science-model, forecasting

The standard flow for time-series that i'm aware of, is that you divide your dataset for Training & Validation  (60% and 20% respectively for example) and the last 20% is used for Unbiased Testing.

**Percentages aside,** is there benefit in having the Testing being split into 2 chunks? for example 10% in the middle 10% in the end. Or just using the 20% middle. Any simple theory references to check would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the test set into two separate chunks in the middle and at the end may not provide any additional benefits and may even introduce some `bias`, as it may not reflect the real-world scenario of predicting future observations. In some cases, researchers may use cross-validation methods to split the data into multiple folds to train and evaluate the model on different subsets of the data.

In general, the choice of the splitting method depends on the specific problem and the data being used. It is important to carefully consider the trade-offs and potential biases introduced by different splitting methods and select the one that is most appropriate for the problem at hand.

Some references on this topic include:

Chapter 8 of the book `"Hands-On Time Series Analysis with R"` by `Rami Krispin`, which covers time-series data splitting and cross-validation.
The paper `"A comparative study on time series data prediction using traditional and deep learning methods"` by `Anjana R. Nair` and `Jyothi R. Nair`, which discusses the impact of different data splitting methods on time-series prediction performance.